# Fazer timer de efeito na unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

ola eu estou fazendo um jogo de plataforma 2d na unity e eu fiz um item que ao voce pegalo voce conseguira pular mais alto porem eu gostaria de colocar um timer (nao quero que apareca na tela)para o efeito passar depois de um tempo especifico e nao sei como voces poderiam me ajudar este o codigo do meu item

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Crystal : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Boost")]
    [SerializeField] float jumpBoost = 10f;

    [Header("SFX")]
    [SerializeField] AudioClip pickupSFX;
    [SerializeField] [Range(1f, 10f)] float pickupSFXVolume = 10f;

    //cached referns
    Player player;

    private void Start()
    {
        player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(pickupSFX, Camera.main.transform.position, pickupSFXVolume);
        player.jumpForce += jumpBoost;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 0):

Esse é um jeito de pra fazer o efeito passar depois de um tempo, mas nao tenho certeza se é o mais simples:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class Crystal : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Header("Boost")]
        [SerializeField] float jumpBoost = 10f;
        [SerializeField] float boostTime; // tempo que vai levar para o efeito passar (em segundos)
            
        [Header("SFX")]
        [SerializeField] AudioClip pickupSFX;
        [SerializeField] [Range(1f, 10f)] float pickupSFXVolume = 10f;
        
        private bool boosting;
        private float boostTimer;
        private float normalJumpForce;
            
        //cached referns
        Player player;
        
        private void Awake()
        {
            normalJumpForce = player.jumpForce;
            boostTimer = boostTime; // Faz o timer comecar no maximo.
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (boosting)
            {
                player.jumpForce = normalJumpForce + jumpBoost;
                boostTimer -= Time.deltaTime; // Faz o timer do efeito diminuir com o tempo.

                if (boostTimer <= 0) // Se o tempo do efeito acabar.
                {
                    boostTimer = boostTime; // Reseta o timer.
                    boosting = false; // Para de fazer o efeito.
                }
            }
    
        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(pickupSFX, Camera.main.transform.position, pickupSFXVolume);
            boosting = true;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cara valeu por tentar ajudar mas vou deixar do outro jeito mesmo

Comment: Blz, boa sorte com seu jogo!